# Align checkbox to top left of text

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML code:

```
<div id="parent">
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <div id="child">Sample checkbox text on the way</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
input {
   width: 10%;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size:16px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
#child {
   width: 88%;
   display: inline-block;
}
#parent {
   width: 240px;
}
```

The checkbox is aligned to the bottom left to the text. How can I make it aligned to the top left instead? Similar to float effect.

I made a jsfiddle for you to play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/zm9onLxf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `input` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fhzmyLuo/)**

```css
input {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#child {
    width: 88%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#parent {
    width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div id="child">Sample checkbox text on the way</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to simply add the following CSS to your stylesheet in order to align the `checkbox` perfectly inline with the text:

```
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#child {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

```css
input {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#child {
    width: 88%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#parent {
    width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div id="child">Sample checkbox text on the way</div>
</div>
```